# Problems with android k4l-video-trimmer library

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-studio-3.0

Is anyone used https://github.com/titansgroup/k4l-video-trimmer library for cropping video on Android?

Yesterday all worked fine. Today I'm open the project, created the build, without any changes, run it and try to crop video and got exception

```
 08-01 15:53:20.515 13722-14119/com.urazito.matreshka E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-4-thread-1
Process: com.urazito.matreshka, PID: 13722
java.lang.RuntimeException: A cast to int has gone wrong. Please contact the mp4parser discussion group (4009305683)
at com.googlecode.mp4parser.util.CastUtils.l2i(CastUtils.java:30)
at com.googlecode.mp4parser.AbstractBox.parse(AbstractBox.java:110)
at com.coremedia.iso.AbstractBoxParser.parseBox(AbstractBoxParser.java:107)
at com.googlecode.mp4parser.BasicContainer.next(BasicContainer.java:185)
at com.googlecode.mp4parser.BasicContainer.hasNext(BasicContainer.java:161)
at com.googlecode.mp4parser.util.LazyList.blowup(LazyList.java:30)
at com.googlecode.mp4parser.util.LazyList.size(LazyList.java:77)
at com.googlecode.mp4parser.BasicContainer.getBoxes(BasicContainer.java:80)
at com.googlecode.mp4parser.authoring.samples.DefaultMp4SampleList.<init>(DefaultMp4SampleList.java:36)
at com.coremedia.iso.boxes.mdat.SampleList.<init>(SampleList.java:33)
at com.googlecode.mp4parser.authoring.Mp4TrackImpl.<init>(Mp4TrackImpl.java:64)
at com.googlecode.mp4parser.authoring.container.mp4.MovieCreator.build(MovieCreator.java:57)
at life.knowledge4.videotrimmer.utils.TrimVideoUtils.genVideoUsingMp4Parser(TrimVideoUtils.java:72)
at life.knowledge4.videotrimmer.utils.TrimVideoUtils.startTrim(TrimVideoUtils.java:65)
at life.knowledge4.videotrimmer.K4LVideoTrimmer$5.execute(K4LVideoTrimmer.java:354)
at life.knowledge4.videotrimmer.utils.BackgroundExecutor$Task.run(BackgroundExecutor.java:212)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:152)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:265)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

How it possible?? There was no changes. At all..

In CastsUtil i'm found this method

```
public static int l2i(long l) {
    if (l > Integer.MAX_VALUE || l < Integer.MIN_VALUE) {
        throw new RuntimeException("A cast to int has gone wrong. Please contact the mp4parser discussion group (" + l + ")");
    }
    return (int) l;
}
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: What about asking the developpers at the lib-s [issue tracker](https://github.com/titansgroup/k4l-video-trimmer/issues)?

Comment: I tried, but new issues not adding...